# Build 3 different multiple regression models that predict

Tags: r

I am trying to build a multiple regression model (multi_model) and I want to build 3 different multiple regression models that predict hourly demand for a day based on hourly temperature and hourly windspeed, varied by the level of weather (levels 1, 2, and 3).

Sample of my data set called "Bike Share Demand:

```
    datetime    season  holiday workingday  weather temp    atemp   humidity    windspeed   casual  registered  count
1/1/2011 0:00        1      0         0         1   9.84    14.395        81       0           3     13          16
1/1/2011 1:00        1      0          0        2   9.02    13.635        80       0           8    32           40
1/1/2011 2:00         1     0          0        3   9.02    13.635        80       0           5    27           32
```

except, there are 10,887 rows. but you get the idea.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reticulate)
library(readxl)
library(modelr)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)

type_1 <- read.csv("Bike Share Demand.csv")


type_1 %>%
  separate(datetime, into = c("month", "day",
                              "year", "hour", sep = "/")) -> type_1
```

I have been trying to build my code for this question:

```
avg_windspeed <- type_1$windspeed
avg_windspeed <- mean(avg_windspeed)

demand <- type_1$registered
total_demand <- sum(demand)

type_1 %>%
  separate(hour, into = c("v_hour", "v_min", sep = ":")) -> type_1
type_1


class(type_1$hour)
hours <- type_1$v_hour
hours

hour <- type_1$hour

rm(total_hours)
hours <- as.numeric(hours)
total_hours <- sum(hours,na.rm = TRUE)
total_hours

temperature <- type_1$temp
temperature
total_temperature <- sum(total_temperature)
total_temperature

windspeed <- type_1$windspeed
hourly_windspeed <- windspeed / hours 
hourly_windspeed

hourly_demand <- demand / total_hours
hourly_demand

hourly_temperate <- temperature / hours
hourly_temperate

multi_model <- lm(data = type_1, demand ~ hourly_windspeed)
summary(multi_model)
```

But i get the error:
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : NA/NaN/Inf in 'x'

Any simpler ways to build this multi model? I am overcomplicating this by creating all these variables?

Comment: You have NA values in your independent variable so the estimation can't be performed. You might be able to find and them with `is.na(x)` and/or the tidyr `parse` functions.

Comment: Generally NA values in data just get the rows ignored by the `lm` function. Did you perhaps divide by zero? Errors resolution generally require enough data to reproduce the error.

Comment: My close vote was because attempting to figure out where the error arises cannot be completed without data that causes the error.